# Internet explorer 8 displays my webpage as blank page, but shows no issues in the developer tools

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have built this website for a customer which is in hebrew, and now i'm trying to make it work in older browsers, now the only really mayor issue in older browsers is that **IE8 shows a completely blank page**.
the website is already live, you can check it out here:
http://doctorice.co.il/
I don't have any clue about the cause of the issue.

Please help me, i'm slowly dying here...

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the issue was hidden in one of my fonts(from googles api).
it was corrupted, "Open Sans Hebrew". fixed it and uploaded to my server and now it works.